# Converge multiple rows of an CSV in one

Tags: python, csv, rows

I have a CSV in which a student appears on multiple lines. The goal is to obtain a CSV where the student's name appears only once and a "Sports" column is created where all the sports practiced by the student separated by a space converge (like the photos)

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Jul.png)

[final csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNW4D.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to post a full solution, as this sounds like a homework problem. If this is infact for a school assignment, please edit your question to include the information.

From your description, the problem can be broken into three steps, each of which can be independently written as code in your solution.

1. Parse a CSV file
2. Create a new data structure that reduces the number of rows and adds a new column
3. Output the data to a new CSV file.

Step 1 and 3 are the simplest. You will want to use things like `with open('file', 'r')`, `list.split()`, and `",".join()`

For step 2, the problem is eaiser to understand if you think in terms of dictionaries. If you can turn your original data (which is a **list** of rows) into a **dictionary** of rows, then it becomes eaiser to detect duplicates. All dictionaries must have a unique key (or column in this case), and you already know that you have a key (student name) that you would like to be unique, but isn't.

Your code for step 2 will iterate over the list of rows, adding each one to a dictionary using *student_name* as a unique key. If that key already exists, then instead of adding a new entry, you will need to *modify* the existing entry's "sports" field.